# How to solve simultaneous equations of exponential powers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the following simultaneous equations?

1. $x + y + z = 0$
2. $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 = 1$
3. $x^3 +y^3 +z^3 = 0$

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: The first equation implies $z=-x-y$; substitute that into the third equation and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Because of equation 1, we know that the average of $x$, $y$, and $z$ is $0$. If one takes into account that $z=-x-y$, and substitutes this for $z$ in equation 3, we get:

$$x^3+y^3+(-x-y)^3=0$$

The third term, $(-x-y)^3$, can be worked out to $(-x^3-3x^2y-3xy^2-y^3)$. The first two terms are canceled out, leaving us with:

$$-3x^2y-3xy^2=0$$

We can divide both sides by $x$ and $y$, leaving: $-3x-3y=0$. This can be simplified as:

$$x+y=0$$

That shows that either $x$ and $y$ are opposites, or they are both equal to $0$.  If they are both zero, then the average of $x$, $y$, and $z$ cannot be $0$, unless $z=0$ as well, but the second equation shows that at least one of them must be a non-zero number; therefore, x and y are opposites.

Because $x$ and $y$ are opposites, the average of $x$, $y$, and $z$ cannot be $0$ unless $z=0$, and, as we have already established that this is true, $z$ must equal $0$. This turns equation 2 into $x^2+y^2=1$. As $x^2$ and $y^2$ are equal, this can be worked out as $2x^2=1$, simplified as $x^2=0.5$, showing that:

$$x=±\sqrt{0.5}$$

$y$ having already been established as the opposite of $x$, the solution set must include both $\sqrt{0.5}$ and $-\sqrt{0.5}$, making the solution set $\{-\sqrt{0.5}, 0, \sqrt{0.5}\}$

Answer (score 0):

As x+y+z=0 =>$x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz$
so from eq (3) 3xyz=0 =>at least one of x,y or z must be zero and from eq (1) and (2) no two or all of them can be zero.This implies only one of x,y or z is zero and the other two are equal in magnitude but apposite in sign.

So the solution set is $\{-\frac 1{\sqrt 2},0,\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\}$